# Monitor WIFI direct activities on Android

Tags: android, wifi-direct

Is there a way to monitor wifi direct activities in ICS?

Like a netstat command that list all open ports and ip, etc...

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wifi direct only sets up a net interface and IP.

so yes, you can use netstat to check connections